# Avoiding Run-time Parameter Tests

Tags: macros, global-variables, runtime, common-lisp

My prototype program initially defines a number of global parameters, which subsequently affect the course of analysis. But the program body ended up containing numerous tests of these parameters to determine how to proceed with the detailed analysis. For example:

```
(defparameter *param1* 0)

(ecase *param1*
  (0 (foo))
  (1 (bar))
  (2 (baz)))
```

But performing all these various tests at run-time is inefficient. Can these tests be effectively moved to compile-time (or handled otherwise), since all of the parameters are known before analysis begins?

My first idea was to build macros for the tests, so only the relevant code is available at run-time:

```
(defmacro param1-macro ()
  (ecase *param1*
    (0 `(foo))
    (1 `(bar))
    (2 `(baz))))
```

But having calls like (param1-macro) scattered throughout makes the code hard to read and analyze during debugging. The unique decision process for each macro call is then nonlocal. Is there a more transparent way to increase run-time efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these parameters are compile-time constants then make them constants (ie define them with `defconstant`).  This should give the compiler a chance to make assumptions about their values at compile time and turn conditionals into unconditional execution.

How well the compiler can do this depends on the compiler of course: in my limited testing at least some CL compilers do this kind of optimisation.

I'd certainly try to do this before a lot of second-guessing-the-compiler-with-macros.

Another thing, of course, is to raise tests (this must have a name, but I'm not sure what it is: I always call it just 'raising').  Turn code like

```
(dotimes (i big-number)
  (case *parameter*
    ((1) ...)
    ...))
```

into

```
(case *parameter*
  ((1) (dotimes (i big-number)
         ...))
  ...)
```

Which reduces the number of tests by a factor of `big-number`.  I suspect this also is an optimisation that good compilers can do themselves.

Finally and perhaps most importantly: measure how slow it is.  Are the tests *really* taking a long time?  Almost certainly unless you have measured their cost you don't know it: certainly that's what I find whenever I make assumptions like that!

---

As an alternative to the above here is a really horrible hack which will allow you to use parameters but will wire in their *compile-time* values, thus causing the compiler to treat them like constants.  Note: when I say 'horrible' I also mean 'mostly untested'.

Here is how you can do this:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defvar *wiring* t))

(declaim (inline wiring))

(defun wiring (x)
  x)

(define-compiler-macro wiring (&whole form x)
  (if (and *wiring*
           (symbolp x)
           (boundp x))
      `(quote ,(symbol-value x))
    form))
```

Now, if `*wiring*` is false at compile time `(wiring ...)` is a just an identity function, so you can say `(wiring *param*)` to mean `*param*`.  It's declared inline so it should have zero cost (and, really, zero purpose).

But if `*wiring*` is *true* at compile-time, then the compiler macro does a horrible thing: `(wiring *param*)` will:

1. check if `*param*` is a symbol;
2. if it is, and if it is bound then it will expand to its *compile-time* value (quoted for safety).

This means, that if, at compile time, `*param*` is bound to `2`, then

```
(case (wiring *param*)
  ((2) (+ x 0))
  (otherwise (+ x 1)))
```

is equivalent, at compile time, to

```
(case 2
  ((2) (+ x 0))
  (otherwise (+ x 1)))
```

And the compiler can then turn this (with a note in the case of SBCL) into `(+ x 0)`.

This is horrid because ... well, there are very many ways it is horrid.  It certainly violates a lot of assumptions about how code should behave.  But it's also kind of lovely: you can do this in Lisp, within the language, which I think is amazing.

Comment: How would this work with defconstant? The "constants" might be set to different values on subsequent runs. Recompiling everything between runs is OK, but won't this generate compiler errors for defconstant? (ps: using SBCL)

Comment: @davypough: Yes, it's not allowed to redefine constants and SBCL is fussy about that.  The easy approach is just to cold-start the Lisp before recompiling if you redefine them.  If you can't do that then blowing away the package things are defined in will work.

Comment: @davypough: I've added an addendum with a rather disgusting hack which you might want to look at.  *Caveat emptor*!

Comment: Elegant update! That's definitely going in my toolbox, although it may be a little much for my current parameters. On some review, it looks like the the extra time to check the numerous parameters at runtime is miniscule (but not sure how to verify this, since they are so widespread). Nice idea about putting them all in a separate package, too. Thanks for a deep answer.